# How to add number to current CSS width with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, percentage

I'm working on a meter that goes up or down depending on decisions you make.

I'm doing this by changing the width percentage of the CSS with jQuery.

Currently I can set it to an arbitrary percent, but I want to add or subtract a percentage from the current value.

How would I do this?

My code:

```
        $("#meter").css("width", "40%");
        $(".fan-percent").text("40%");
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="fanHappiness">

<h4 class="white">Fan Happiness:</h4>

<div id="meter">

    <h4 class="white fan-percent">50%</h4>

</div>
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Using this code I've gotten it too work, but it only subtracts or adds from the original number, so if I add 25 to the original 50, then subtract 25, I don't get 50, I get 25. Maybe storing the number in a variable after retrieving it from the CSS would help.

```
        $("#meter").width($("#meter").width() + 25);
        $(".fan-percent").text($(".fan-percent").width() + 25 + "%");
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: @technophobia I think he already has shown us what he has done. And question is valid.

Comment: @technophobia right above the HTML is the jQuery I currently use to set the CSS width / text, I didn't include the button press function because it wasn't really important to the question, I've tried adding a + symbol in a few different spots but obviously that didn't work, so I'm here asking for help.

Comment: @npav42 roger that, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var percent = "40%";  
    $("#meter").css("width", percent);
    $(".fan-percent").text(percent);
});

function addHappiness(){
    var currentPercent = $("#meter")[0].style.width.slice(0,-1);
    newpercent = +currentPercent + 10;
    $("#meter").css("width", newpercent + "%");
    $(".fan-percent").text(newpercent + "%");
}
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dnyseaen/1/

Comment: Please note that there is no buffer logic in that demo, so it will allow over 100%. You'll want to add some logic there.

Answer (score 1):

$("#meter").css("width") will return the percentage; therefore, you could split the returned value based on the "/" and then increment/decrement the isolated number. Once that is done, you can update the css and text. Let me know if this is not clear, and/or you need some code to visualize.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if you could show some code that would be great, but I'll take what you said and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t6o3oazy/

This should get you on the right track. Note how I write to the console so you can see how the value is extracted. Manipulate this value as you want, then update the css with jQuery such as $("#meter").css("width", newValue);

Hope this helps